# How to change domain path based on MySQL fields?

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I apologise if this is in the wrong place, but I searched around and this seemed appropriate.

Essentially my problem is this: I have a MySQL database called `goals`. There is a composite primary key of `season` and `gots`. To explain, `season` is whichever season the goal was scored (e.g. 2014-2015) and `gots` is the number that goal was in the season (e.g. 14 = 14th goal scored that season). Hence, together they are unique.

What I want is to have every entry in the table (every goal) to have it's own path on my website in the format `https://domain.com/%season%/%gots%` (e.g. `https://domain.com/2014-2015/32`) which would refer to the 32nd goal scored in the 2014-2015 season. Under that domain, I'd have a generic HTML/PHP page that contains all the relevant information about the goal.

How can I do this such that when I create a new entry in the table a URL path as described above is automatically created and the data corresponding to that entry in the table is automatically inserted in the page template?

Thank you very much!

Comment: answer would depend on if you are using a php framework or not, and also which webserver you are using (apache, nginx, etc) - what you are trying to do is called 'routing' or 'url rewriting'.

Comment: Google for PHP seo friendly urls

Comment: You have to work with mod_rewrite available in apache (may vary from webserver to webserver as @pala_ said) and split the path in php by slash. You receive an array like ['2014-2015', '32']. Based on this array you can build your query/queries.

Comment: Try to create url dynamically in php at the time of saving values and create a column where you can save it's information whose datatype is longtext. when you want to show based on url get the id and fetch the information and sow.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. The webserver is Litespeed (so mod_rewrite and .htaccess is fine). By using mod_rewrite though would people be able to directly access the links such as `https://domain.com/2014-2015/32`? Or would it only work under a "redirect". Cheers

Comment: User requestes domain.com/2014-2015/32/ and mod_rewrite uses regex to redirect to a specific get parameter and assign the path to this get parameter. The path can be accessed in php via $_GET['view']. "view" is just a sample. You can use any other string, too. In this case the redirect url will be: index.php?view=2014-2015/32/

Comment: it would still show in the browser is /2014-2015/32/ btw

Comment: Thank you everyone, I got it sorted. I ended up using htaccess such that anything like https://domain.com/season/1415 actually points to https://domain.com/season.php?id=1415. Appreciate the help!